# Error when starting Ubuntu from usb

Tags: boot

Recently I have installed Ubuntu on a usb. I booted it a few times, and it worked well, but when I tried to boot it today, it gave me this error:

[image: The error]

When I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> it shows the ubuntu logo and it shuts off. How to fix it?

Comment: Please provide more details to clerify your problem.                   What version of ubuntu you are running? What usb you are using?    In which pc your trying to boot? Is it the same device you have already booted successfuly?

Comment: Please tell us more, otherwise we can only guess and not really help you: What computer is it: brand name and model? Which version of Ubuntu (20.04.3 LTS or some other version)? How did you create the USB boot drive: Which tool and method? What operating system is there in the internal drive?

Comment: That is not an error. What happens after that?

Comment: It's the same usb stick with Ubuntu 20.04.4. The stick is a 114gb SanDisk USB. I think it's called "SanDisk MegaFit" or "UltraFit" or something like that. All happened on the same pc. Specs: 8gb ram, Intel i5 coffee lake, nvidia 1660 super, 222gb hard disk running windows 10. The problem happened after I changed the boot order so it boots from the USB without me manually changing the boot device every time I want to boot Ubuntu. Even after changing the boot order back to default, and trying to boot the usb in virtualbox it gives me the same message. After the "error" comes up, nothing happens

Comment: Sounds like you somehow messed something when setting new boot order. If you change boot settings back as they were, does the stick (and Windows when not using the stick) boot properly?

Comment: Windows boots normally, but the stick doesn't change.

Comment: Thanks for the details :-) Please tell us also how you made the bootable USB drive: Which tool and method? Is it a plain live drive (live-only), or a persistent live drive or an installed system? The answers to those questions will bring us a long way towards understanding what drive it is, and then we can start asking you to check various things that might cause the problem.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu on a drive. Full installation, not a live USB, I did it by connecting the USB to a virtualbox vm and installing the os on the USB.

Comment: First try to find out if the problem is caused by a change in Ubuntu or in the UEFI/BIOS system of the computer. You can start like this: try to boot some other computers with the USB drive (in the same boot mode UEFI or BIOS alias legacy mode as in the original computer). Check if UEFI boot or BIOS boot and change it. When UEFI mode, turn off secure boot. If you suspect Ubuntu, boot from another drive and repair the file system and try again. After that check carefully if something more is written to the screen and let us know. -- In UEFI mode, Windows sometimes destroys booting of Ubuntu.